# Interactive Jupyter widgets in VSCode with ms-python 2018.10.1

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I am using VSCode 1.27.2 and the ms-python 2018.10.1 extension with the new "Data Science features" on Windows 7.

Is there any way of getting jupyter interactive widgets to work?

This example generates a slider in the jupyter notebook...

[image: interact example in jupyter]

...while VSCode only prints the default value 10:

[image: interact example in VSCode]

I understand that this feature in VSCode is in an early state. I want to know if it is a limitation or if I am missing something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Support for `ipywidgets` has been released on 20 April 2020 (see [Changelog](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items/ms-python.python/changelog)).

(Original answer: It is indeed a known limitation, ipywidgets are not supported as of today. See [this issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/issues/3429) in the vscode-python repository.)